# Finding birth certificate from late 19th century Transylvania

Tags: birth-records, vital-records, romania, birthplace, transylvania

I am trying to find birth certificate or details about my great grandparents who were from Transylvania.
My great grandfathers name was Marton Joszef and my great grandmother was Sarlota Lefkorits. They had 2 sons Alexander Joszef born 7 May 1913 in Bobota (who was my grandfather - and his brother Ernest).

I know my great grandparents both perished in the Holocaust, but I would like to find out some more information to create a family tree

Comment: In the later 1800s, the area that counted as Transylvania was 15 counties of the Kingdom of Hungary. That's both much too large an area for genealogical purposes and much smaller than the area that's considered Transylvania today (i.e., everything in Romania that's west of the Carpathians).

Comment: According to Dvorzsák's gazetteer, both Kis-Derzsida and Nagy-Derzsida in Szilágy county were sometimes known as Babota (https://kt.lib.pte.hu/cgi-bin/kt.cgi?konyvtar/kt03110501/0_0_1_pg_609.html). It appears that Bobota is the Romanian name of Nagyderzsida.

Comment: Likely correct spellings: Marton Jozsef and Sarolta Lefkovits.